# Odoo remove job after fail?

Tags: python, odoo

I want to unlink failed job in my class

I want to delete a job if the state is failed, how can I delete it after the job fail ?

I need similar code as the following. 
Can anyone help me ?

```
@job(default_channel='root')
@api.model
def process_incoming_events(self, event):
    try:
        do...
    catch:
        job.unlink()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In method of job, you can't find the result of that job.
You can find result and updated state after method executed.

Comment: How can i find after execute?

Comment: May I know which version of Odoo you are using and which module you are using?

Comment: Odoo 11 enterprise

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an automation(ir.cron), the automation will run with scheduled and running your code to remove or unlink the datas.
you can find in Setting -> Technical -> Automation